# Error using survSplit function

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm rerunning code from 2 years ago and am encountering a new error with the survSplit function. The error says that my object cannot be found, even though it is a defined column in my dataframe.

Here is an example of my dataframe:

```
f12 <- data.frame(id = 1:6,
              next.ivl= c(22.348, 1.837, 2.051,1.782,1.692, 1.730),
              event = c(0,1,1,0,1,1),
              enter= rep(0,6),
              end=c(22.348, 1.837,2.051,1.782,1.629,1.730))
```

My previous code was the following:

```
cutpoints.l <- c(10/12, 1.25, 1.75, 2.25, seq(3,11))

f12.split <- survSplit(f12, 
                   cut = cutpoints.l, 
                   event = "event", 
                   start = "enter", 
                   end = "next.ivl", 
                   episode = "ivl")
```

I went ahead and tried running the example code provided [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/survSplit.html) (also below), and am getting another error ("Error in Surv(time, status) : Time variable is not numeric." These errors seem to be related. What's going on? Why would I get an error with the example code?

```
library(survival)    
aml3<-survSplit(aml,cut=c(5,10,50),end="time",start="start",
            event="status",episode="i")
```

FYI: currently running R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)

Update for future reference: the correct code should be

```
f12.split <- survSplit(Surv(next.ivl,event)~.,f12, 
                 cut = cutpoints.l,
                event = "event",
                start = "enter", 
                 end = "next.ivl",
                 episode = "ivl")
```

Comment: please post your data so we can help

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian: The `aml` dataset is part of the survival package which ships with every complete installation package of R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument is supposed to be formula and you are giving it a data.frame. I realize this reference page appears to be a recent (even cutting edge) version looking at the URL but the current released version of pkg:survival is 2.39-5 and that page is referencing version 2.38-3. The current version of the help page for `survSplit` does reference an earlier version of the function which lacked a formula interface and has examples that run without error on my instance of R 3.3.1.

Comment: Thanks-- it sounds like I'm using an older formulation of the function. (And apologies for the extra post-- this is my first question on here!)