# survSplit ... Error in survSplit(data = bc, cut = bc$time[bc$status == 1], end = "time", : start time must be < stop time

Tags: r, survival-analysis

Error:

> survSplit  .... Error in `survSplit(data = bc, cut = bc$time[bc$status == 1], end = "time",` : start time must be `<` stop time

I am getting this error because I have a `survival time` equal to `0` in my database which will make me get this error. Is there any way to fix it?

I am using *[david collette recurrence of bladder cancer data](https://www.crcpress.com/Modelling-Survival-Data-in-Medical-Research-Third-Edition/Collett/p/book/9781439856789)* to create a time dependent variable in R.

Comment: I think we need to see the code that generates this error. Please add it as an [edit] to the body of your question. (No code in Comments, please.)

Comment: [rstudio] tag removed because the function is from the `survival` package. Nothing to do with Rstudio.

Comment: Furthermore I don't see a formula in the error message and I'm wondering if my answer to an earlier question applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39216319/error-using-survsplit-function